# Improving LT Spice DC sweep convergence time

Tags: ltspice

I have a circuit that's kind of finicky, I'm trying to run a DC sweep but it takes forever to run simulation steps. The main problem is even after adding circuit elements to make the circuit converge faster\better (like parallel resistance and capacitance on sources, and parasitic capacitance and series source resistance), the circuit still takes a long time and won't stop stepping the source or not converging (I don't know whats going on under the hood).

I get this at the bottom of the screen:

[image]

To make it run faster I hit esc because it is done stepping but probably not to the tolerance that some setting requires. If I even run 10 steps this takes about 15 mins of my time that I could be doing something else, I would like to run 30 steps, but that would take a long time.

How do I set the limit for the source stepping or stop it?

How can I get the steps to run back to back so I don't have to babysit the simulation by hitting the ESC key?

Comment: Run it overnight while you sleep - or schedule it to run in the background - used to run simulations that took 40 days or more but that was on a Unix system....

Comment: Thats silly, its eating up CPU cycles doing absolutely nothing. Sometimes the simulations never finish because they don't reach the right criteria, I want to change the criteria. NO, I want someone to tell me whats going on, and what criteria I can change.

Comment: Do you normally use ALL of your cpu cycles with useful work?

Comment: Some of the behavioral sources are fussy, needing delay time or hysteresis

Comment: I need answers fast, time = money.

Comment: It's your time that you are paid for, not us....

Comment: If you allowed it to (finally) converge to a solution then you may get information that would help you achieve a more rapid convergence.

Comment: No, because the simulation is probably bouncing between two values at some value say - 10uV I don't want to know about uV right now. I'll bet there is some way to stop convergence at a value higher than that. Part of the problem if the solver can't find a solution, it turns off all of the AC components and tries to find a DC solution.

Comment: Are you doing mixed-signal analysis? (Analog & digital). Different engines are used for each domain. Perhaps converging problems result.

Comment: Just analog, I've tried changing solvers

Comment: @solarMike I put in my due diligence on this site, I have spent a fair amount of time answering others questions. I would suggest you do the same. If you don't know the answer, then move on

Comment: You might need to add some small valued capacitors in some key points in your schematic, to help convergence in the case of abrupt changes. You could also use current sources with parallel resistors, instead of voltage, they converge better, or you could add `Rser` to the voltage ones (they're converted internally to current). Maybe adding some parasitics, too? I can only guess.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen done that, and parasitic resistance. If a DC simulation fails to converge it removes all caps and tries again. I need to know how to control sweep convergance

Comment: @laptop2d - well my due diligence on this site shows I have posted 0 questions and only answers and have not been on here long.... I suggested allowing the solution to continue to a close as some simulation programs will show where the errors accumulate - especially CFD packages and it is possible to write extra code to throw out interim values so you can check progress easily (very handy when some simulations need 40 days...) - perhaps you could consider that approach and have some critical values for live inspection. However, following your excellent advice - I will move on.

Comment: Did you already try to use the "alternate solver"?

Comment: @Mario Yep that was one of the first things I did

Comment: @laptop2d usually when you hit escape during a DC simulation, it skips to the next convergence strategy, accounting for the behavior you described where hitting escape seems to complete the simulation. Can you post an error log from a converged simulation so we can scrutinize exactly what happened?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you hit escape during a stalled DC simulation in LTSpice, the simulator progresses to the next solution method. The first method is direct Newton-Raphson iteration. If that fails, LTSpice will try the following strategies in order by default:

1. Adaptive gmin stepping
2. Adaptive source stepping
3. "Pseudo Transient"

From your screen shot, it looks like you are still hung up when you get to adaptive source stepping. My guess is that when you hit escape at that point, you progress to the Pseudo Transient method and get convergence relatively quickly thereafter. I see this a lot.

If you know which method is converging well for your circuit and you are confident in the results, then you can avoid baysitting your sim by presenting .options directives that disable the methods that are bound to hang up. From the LTSPice manual, the specific directives are:

> Direct Newton Iteration: .options NoOpIter
>
> Adaptive Gmin Stepping: .options GminSteps=0
>
> Adaptive Source Stepping: .options SrcSteps=0
>
> Pseudo Transient: .options pTranTau=0

Comment: This is awesome, my simulation time went from 30min of me hitting the esc key to 5seconds with no babysitting. Cant thank you enough.

Comment: For those who follow, you need to include all three statements, and turn pTranTau on: `.options GminSteps=0, SrcSteps=0, pTranTau=1`

Comment: Heh, I just ran 600 steps in 5 seconds, this is great

Comment: Np. Do note that pTranTau is a parameter and not a flag. I.e. different (non-zero) values actually effect the pseudo-transient method strategy. The default is 0.1 rather than 1, but I wouldn't expect it to make a big difference.

Comment: Good to know, 1 works great for me